# How to do Java GUI list view like in Android

Tags: java, jlist

I am doing simple Java GUI app. 
I want to implement feature similar to Android ListView. That is, I have list of objects taken from server, and I want to populate some list in Java GUI.
Here is what i have:

```html
 List<Email> emails = FetchingEmail.fetchEmails();
```

So I have List of emails, where email object is a class with some attributes. I want to populate this list of emails into some list view in my gui.

Comment: [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) or possibly even [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: I did something once where I stacked several "row"  JPanels into a JScrollPane. Pretty much acted like a LinearLayout/ListView combination in Android. Sadly don't have the code anymore :/